# Como sacar el porcentaje de dos columnas que tienen suma acomulada en datastudio (Lockerstudio)?

Tags: google-data-studio

Tengo un informe que esta teniendo como fuente de datos BigQuery, lo que deseo es lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La columna 1 y 2 son registros totales, la columna 3 y 4 son registros de una area. Lo que pasa es que las 4 primeras columnas lo que tienen como **Calculo acomulativo** es suma continua, pero cuando intento sacar el porcentaje por ejemplo de la division de la columna 3 entre la columna 1, los porcentajes se calculan del valor real del bigquery y no de la suma continua.

Como puedo lograr que se calculen del valor de la celda y no del valor que tiene el el bigquery.